# Access to swagger api in browser when starting .net core project with docker-compose

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose, swagger

I've a Visual Studio solution with a blazor server project, and some ASP .NET Core Web API projects (they should be the microservices).

I've created the following `docker-compose.yml` with Visual Studio, in order to start everything:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myserver.frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myserverfrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Server/MyServer.Frontend/Dockerfile

  mygateway.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mygatewayapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/MyGateway.API/Dockerfile


  identity.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Identity.API/Dockerfile

  # Install the mongodb for offline data storage
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongo:27017/
```

If I start to debug only the `MyGateway` project, I can see in the browser its swagger ui for debugging. If I start only `MyServer.Frontend`, only the blazor pages.

If I start everything with `docker-compose`, I can see that everything is running, and I can  see the pages in the blazor server.

Is there a way to start everything with `docker-compose.yml` and access also to web core api of other projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger is - by default - only available when you run your webapi in development mode. VS sets that, but docker-compose doesn't.

Add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to your definition like this, and Swagger should be available. You also need to map port 80 to a host port.

```
  mygateway.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mygatewayapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/MyGateway.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
```

Swagger should then be available on `http://localhost:8082/swagger`.

Comment: Thanks. this is really helpful. I've also noticed that I can use something like `docker-compose.override.yml` for creating different presets for different configuration. Probably it's better to add this configuration in that file.